# Display all comparisons for factor variables in R for lm or coxph

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coding-efficiency

In R, the default method when using a factor variable in regression is to use contrasts. I.E we set a reference class, and then the results are reported as (factor) vs. reference.

For example, if we had 3 groups, and set 1 to be the reference group, then the results will be (2 vs 1) and (3 vs 1). But we don't get to see 3 vs 2. I know that you can get this by rerunning the regression and re-leveling with 2 as the reference class. But is there any way to get all comparisons in one line of code, instead of running two regression calls?

Comment: This will work for linear regression, but I don't believe it will work for cox regression, since there is no intercept. Does there exist an analog to this for cox regression?

Comment: Actually, I can answer this myself. The last contrast is just the difference of the beta coefficients. And it seems to generalize. Suppose we have n classes, and reference group 1. For example, to get 4 vs 5, we would to (betacoef of 4 vs 1 - betacoef of 5 vs 1)

Comment: Yes. I tested an example myself (with the factor as the only covariate and with the addition of another covariate). Examples are not proofs, but I feel like this is true, and I also recall one of my professors saying something like this (although I should have remembered what he said first!)